# Logic App - Transform XML using XSLT - Date Format

Tags: xml, xslt, azure-logic-apps

I am using a Logic App connector "Transform XML" with an Integration account having a XSLT map version 3.0 file.

It is working to transform my required XML but when I am including C# code to convert a date tag throwing below exception:

Has anyone got similar issue yet, please let me know.

my XSLT file content

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:userCSharp="urn:my-scripts"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"![97882-error.png][1]
    >
  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="userCSharp">
    <![CDATA[
    public string FormatDateFunction(string inputDate)
    {
    string formatdate;
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputDate))
    return "";
    formatdate = System.DateTime.Parse(inputDate).ToString("M/dd/yyyy");
    return formatdate;
    }
  ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="paramDate">
    <xsl:value-of select="/*/XPathBody/Data" />
  </xsl:variable> 

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <MyHeader_1.0>
      <MyTag>        
        <DueDate>
          <xsl:value-of select="userCSharp:FormatDateFunction($paramDate)"/>          
        </DueDate>        
        <MyDate>          
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$paramDate != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="userCSharp:FormatDateFunction($paramDate)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>          
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>         
        </MyDate>
      </MyTag>
    </MyHeader_1.0>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Error in logic app**

*

```
{
  "Code": "InvalidXsltContent",
  "Message": "An error occurred while transforming the given input with the provided map. Details: 'net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation'.",
  "Details": [
    {
      "Code": "InvalidXsltContent",
      "Message": "{\"StatusCode\":400,\"ErrorCode\":7,\"Details\":null,\"Message\":\"An error occurred while transforming the given input with the provided map. Details: 'net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation'.\",\"Data\":{},\"InnerException\":null,\"TargetSite\":{\"Name\":\"MoveNext\",\"AssemblyName\":\"Microsoft.Azure.Function.Common.Cloud, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\",\"ClassName\":\"Microsoft.Azure.Function.Xslt30Transform.BaseXslt30Transformer+<Transform>d__3\",\"Signature\":\"Void MoveNext()\",\"Signature2\":\"System.Void MoveNext()\",\"MemberType\":8,\"GenericArguments\":null},\"StackTrace\":\"   at Microsoft.Azure.Function.Xslt30Transform.BaseXslt30Transformer.<Transform>d__3.MoveNext() in X:\\\\bt\\\\1186352\\\\repo\\\\src\\\\functions\\\\Scripts\\\\Function.Common.Cloud\\\\Xml\\\\BaseXslt30Transformer.cs:line 75\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\\r\\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Function.Xslt30Transform.Xslt30TransformRequestProcessor.<ProcessTransformRequest>d__2.MoveNext() in X:\\\\bt\\\\1186352\\\\repo\\\\src\\\\functions\\\\Scripts\\\\Function.Xslt30Transform\\\\Xslt30TransformRequestProcessor.cs:line 50\",\"HelpLink\":null,\"Source\":\"Microsoft.Azure.Function.Common.Cloud\",\"HResult\":-2146233088}",
      "Details": null,
      "InnerError": null
    }
  ],
  "InnerError": null
}
```

- 

Attached error image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ8LW.png)

Any help would be much appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: XSLT 3 has support for the XPath 3.1 functions `format-date` and `format-dateTime` so I would try to use them for date formatting. There is also some limited support for date parsing, the "native" XSLT/XPath 2 and later `xs:date` format is `YYYY-MM-DD`, however. But it is usually easy to define your XSLT function to convert from a different date format to the `xs:date` format.

Comment: If you use an XSLT map `version="1.0"` instead of `version="3.0"`, does the embedded C# code work? I don't see anything inside your XSLT making use of XSLT 3 features, thus, if you want to use C# inside of XSLT, you might be able to achieve that using XSLT 1 where I suppose `XslCompiledTransform` is used and not Saxon. Even for XslCompiledTransform, you might need to allow the use of embedded C# inside XSLT.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have tried format-date function as well with both XSLT 2.0 & 3.0, This works fine when I debug it in Visual Studio. The only problem is when I use same XSLT with Azure Integration Account - Map file in Logic Apps, it throws error.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding Logic App connector "Transform XML" does not support XSLT version 3.0. It is also mentioned in the docs.

Please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-maps?tabs=consumption